# LINQ update value in parent rows from ther child rows

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I use linq2sql and **m_DateContext.Dates** class for table

```
ID | ParentID | Datestamp
---|----------|----------
1  | NULL     | 1.8.2010
---|----------|----------
2  | 1        | 2.8.2010
---|----------|----------
3  | 1        | 4.8.2010
```

etc...

I need to write the linq query to select only rows where ParentID is **NULL** (ex: ID=1), BUT Value of DATESTAMP must be equals to max date from it's child rows. (Row ID=3).

Linq query must return an instance of m_DateContext.Dates with non-broken links to entities in database schema.

Result must be smthng like:

```
ID = 1 ParentID=NULL Datestamp = 4.8.2010
```

Please help

Comment: You using linq to entities?  Objects? SQL?  Please give us some classless..

Comment: Thanx, updated. I use linq2sql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All kinds of assumptions (linq to entities or sql) and I think you want a let...

```
var query = (
     from i in TDates
        where i.ParentID==null
     let maxDate= TDates.Max(d=>d.Datestamp) 
     select new {
       NonBrokenRecord = i,
       Datestamp = maxDate
     }

).ToList();
```

Once you get the results you could do...

```
query.ForEach(x=>x.NonBrokenRecord.DateStamp = x.Datestamp);
query = query.Select(x=>x.NonBrokenRecord).ToList();
```

Comment: OK, but in your example i loose connections between all linket entities in database schema - Dtable.OtherEntity.FieldValue

Comment: Well, you need to add this to your question.  Please elaborate on what you mean.

Comment: If I follow that right, Datestamp will be the highest datestamp overall, not the highest where child.ParentId = parentid

Answer (score 2):

```
var rows =
(
from parent in db.Dates
where parentId == null
let MaxDate = parent.Dates.Max(child => child.DateStamp)
select new{DateObject = parent, MaxDate = MaxDate}
)

List<Date> result = new List<Date>();
foreach(var row in rows)
{
  Date d = row.DateObject;
  d.DateStamp = row.MaxDate;
  result.Add(d)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var query = 
    from p in TDates 
    where p.ParentID==null 
    select new TDate 
    { 
        ID = p.ID, 
        ParentID = null, 
        Datestamp = TDates.Where(c=> c.ParentID == p.ID).Max(c=>c.Datestamp)
    };
```

Comment: This is what i dont get, ParentID will always be null?  So your datestamp code would always return the max of all null parentids?

Comment: @Nix: This table (I assume) has a foriegn key relationship into itself where child.ParentID == Parent.ID.  Now, plot your query as if they were two separate tables.  So, ParentID is always null on parent records, but it's not null on the Parent's children's records.

Comment: What i was trying to say is your clause .Where(c=> c.ParentID == p.ID) conflicts with p.ParentID==null  you will always have  .Where(c=> c.ParentID==null)

Comment: @Nix: No conflict. Remember, I said, pretent it's two separate tables. The Datestamp uses a separate query with the only connection to the outer query being p.ID.